# SQL - How to Match Values?

Tags: sql, r

I found this online for practice, but don't know where to begin.

Given a table with three columns (id, category, value) and each id has 3 or fewer possible values (price, size, color).

Now, how can I find those id's for which the value of two or more values matches to one another?

For example: 
ID1 (price 10, size M, color Red),
ID2 (price 10, Size L, Color Red), 
ID3 (price 15, size L, color Red)

Then the output should be two rows: 
ID1 ID2
and ID2 ID3

Comment: Do a self join.

Comment: hmm so would I do 3 different self-joins - one for each column? And then merge the results?

Comment: One self join. Try something like `on (c1 = c1 and c2 = c2) or (c1 = c1 and c3 = c3) or (c2 = c2 and c3 = c3)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data frame `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.ID first, b.ID second
  from DF a 
  join DF b on (a.price = b.price) + 
               (a.size = b.size) + 
               (a.color = b.color) > 1 and
               a.ID < b.ID")
```

giving:

```
  first second
1     1      2
2     2      3
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, 
                 price = c(10, 10, 15), 
                 size = c("M", "L", "L"),
                 color = "Red", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```